# MongoDB how use $elemMatch with a embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I'm do a simple query where i try to filter the users that live in a country, region or city, my document looks like it

```
user: {
    email: 'alex@site.com',
    password: '2f769b35300d8a674c5d2cc2c2d93467',
    location: {
        city: 'Ciudad Obregon',
        region: 'Sonora',
        country: 'Mexico'
    }
}
```

and i want to do something like *db.users.find({'location.country':'Mexico'})* but doesn't work.
I try to use $elementMatch and works but only when a embedded document is a collection,
my question is if posible use $elemMatch without the embedded document be a array?

Comment: so `users` is a collection and each document is structured `user:{//something}`. Is that right?
In that case your query should be `db.users.find({'user.location.country':'Mexico'})`

Comment: did the above comment work for you? Or did I understand your requirement incorrectly?